# Leaflet-locatecontrol color and fillColor

Tags: leaflet

I would modify the color and fillColor properties of Leaflet-locatecontrol but nothing happens:

```
import "leaflet.locatecontrol";
const props = {
  options: {
    type: Object,
    default() {
      return {
        drawCircle: false,
        zoom: 16,
        setView: "always",
        initialZoomLevel: 16,
        showCompass: true,
        color: 'black',
        fillColor: 'red',
        strings: {
          ... 
       },
     };
   },
 },
 ...
```

};
It is the right way, please?

Comment: Do you want to change the dot's color and fillcolor?

Comment: Oh, Hi! Yes, I do. I tried to change them but nothing happened.